# Correct usage it Or that

Tags: pronouns

I am unsure, should I use pronoun it or that at the end of this sentence.

The legislature seems to talk at great length about reform but to do almost nothing to achieve **it/that**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both **it** or **that** are correct but I think **it** is better.

Your sentence has an extra word 'to'

> The legislature seems to talk at great length about reform but **to** do
>   almost nothing to achieve it/that.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

The legislature talks at great length about reform but does almost nothing to achieve it.